# HTML drag & drop in react -- seeing the same id at target, srcElement, and toElement?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a drop zone specified in React with the `onDragOver` handler calling :

```
dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

My `draggable="true"` element has an `onDragEnd` handler with:

```
dragEnd(e) {
  console.log(e.nativeEvent)
}
```

When I drag this element into my drop zone, I'm getting the same id (the item being dragged) for the target, srcElement, and toElement.  I'm trying to figure out why I'm not seeing the id anywhere for the drop zone itself.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yea, that happened with me also , couldn't figure why.

BUT , I  made a **workAround** , to get the **id** of the source element , at destination element :

By using :  `e.dataTransfer.setData`  to pass the id of the Source Element , as in this example :

```
e.dataTransfer.setData("myObj", srcID);
```

and at destination Element , you get the srcID by :

```
e.nativeEvent.dataTransfer.getData("myObj")
```